# Iframe loading with previous selected view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, iframe

I have different anchor tags on my main view and also a popup div with an iframe. when clicked the anchor tags, different views are loaded to the iframe.  My issue is when I click first anchor tag the iframe is loaded with a view which perfect. When I click the next anchor tag, the iframe initially shows the previous view and then only the selected view is loaded. The previous view is shown in the iframe for few seconds before loading the selected view.

the jquery for showing the iframe popup div is

```
$("#crtSubInstn").live("click", function(e) {
            $(".iframe_popup_window").fadeIn();
            $("#popupHead").html("Create Instruction");
            $("#updtFeatures").show();
            $("#popup_content").addClass("editor_iframe");
        });
        $("#udtAttrib").live("click", function(e) {
            $(".iframe_popup_window").fadeIn();
            $("#popupHead").html("Add Attribute");
            $("#updtFeatures").show();
        });
```

There is close button on the popup div which on click hides the popup div with the iframe. The jQuery for the close event is

```
$('.iframe_popup_window_close').live('click', function() { 
    //$("#frmUpdtFeatures").contents().val();
    //window.frames["InstnDetails"].location.reload();
    //$('#frmUpdtFeatures').attr('src', '');
    $("#popup_content").removeClass("editor_iframe");
    $('.iframe_popup_window').fadeOut(function() {
        $('a.close').remove();
    }); //fade them both out

    $(".overlay_iframe").hide();

    return false;
});
```

How can I handle this situation. Can I set the iframe scr to null when closing the popup??

Answer (score 1):

You can set the src to about:blank when the popup is hidden like:

```
$(iframe).attr('src', 'about:blank')
```

This will work on all major browsers.

You can also listen to the iframe's load event, and only show the popup after the frame is loaded. Something like:

```
function showPopup() {
    ... show popup code goes here ...
}

$(iframe).attr('src', '/some/url/here');

$(iframe).load(function() {
  showPopup();
})
```

Onload works inconsistently across browsers for iframes, but might deliver the behavior you're looking for. I'd recommend using both about:blank when hiding the popup, and showing the popup on the iframe's onload event.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you close the iframe, you should clear or hide the content in it and then only show the iframe the next time AFTER you've loaded the new content in.  If you show us more of what you're doing with the content of the iframe and show us the HTML structure in the iframe, we could help in a little more detail.

Comment: i want the same to happen in jquery. ie. clearing the iframe src using jquery part that is used to close the popup. $('.iframe_popup_window_close').live('click', function() {